# How do I play a sound to only the existing party in a conference with Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I want to play a sound to the party that is already in a conference, but not to the other party (half of a the beep="true" parameter in <conference> in other words). The process would be like this:

1. Agent calls into the conference
2. Client is connected into the conference call
3. Agent (ONLY) immediately hears a beep on his side only, the client never hears it

I don't understand how I can easily do this since all the documentation around this seems to be with TwiML's  verb. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to play beep to client before adding him to conference. Try this.

```
<Response>
  <Play>beep mp3</Play>// beep mp3 is beep audio file
  <Dial>
    <Conference>Room 1234</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```